# Error de tiempo en C# con SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo una consulta la cual me da el siguiente error:

'Valor de tiempo de espera caducado. El periodo de tiempo de espera se agotó al intentar consumir la confirmación del protocolo de enlace previo al inicio de sesión. El motivo podría ser que se produjo un error en el protocolo de enlace o que el servidor no pudo responder a tiempo.  El tiempo invertido al intentar conectarse a este servidor fue: [Previo al inicio de sesión] inicialización=15717; protocolo de enlace=0;'

Mi cadena de conexión es la siguiente:

```
connectionString="data source=10.3.0.198;initial catalog=LocalPablo;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=400"
```

Comment: Ese es un error de conexión. Revisa que haya conexión entre el cliente y el servidor.

Comment: Si tengo conexión, pues mando un ping y es exitoso.

Comment: Y los puertos están abiertos? El servidor permite conexiones remotas?

Comment: Cuales puertos deben estar abiertos?

Comment: Si es el default, sería el 1433.

Comment: Y no usas usuario y contraseña en tu base de datos? Checa [este post](https://www.infotutoriales.info/2016/06/net-error-valor-de-tiempo-de-espera.html#:~:text=%E2%80%9CValor%20de%20tiempo%20de%20espera,ejecutar%20la%20solicitud%20Web%20actual.)